# handling multiple array in view sent by controller function in laravel

Tags: laravel

How to send multiple arrays in different controller functions in Laravel 5 and how to handle them in view?

I am getting errors on variable:

> variable not defined

which I am using to retrieve array.

```
 public function index()
{
    $users = user::all();
    return view('employee')->with('users',$users);        
}
```

this is my index, i am sending another array with different function like

```
public function goempedit($id)
{
    $emp = Employee::where('id', $id)->first();
    return view('employee')->with('emp', $emp);
}
```

So at the view I am using foreach loop to print the values but it is not working... `$emp` in `foreach` showing error as:

> not defined variable

Please somebody help.

Answer (score 0):

Just put a simple check like:

```
if(isset($emp)) {

//do  foreach($emp ...
}

if(isset($users)) {
//do $users ($users...
}
```

Comment: thanks, but $emp at second function not showing any value in the view

Comment: @if(isset($emp))
{{$emp->name}}
@endif   somthing like this.. i cant paste here its to long

Comment: see below , suppose $row is $emp .... and want to show edit form in model. but the problem is controller not returning any value. $row is empty or null

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="<?php echo 'Edititem/'.$value->item_id; ?>"  data-toggle="modal" data-target=".edit-items">Edit</a>
//link to call model

//model
<div class="modal fade edit-items" style="z-index: 2000">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Edit Items</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">

          @if(isset($row))

                <form action="{{action('ProductController@edit')}}" method="post">
                  <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
                  <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <h1 style="text-align:center;">Edit Items</h1>
                    <table  class="table">
                            <thead>
                            <tr>
                              <th>ID</th>
                              <th>Category</th>
                              <th>Item</th>
                              <th>Price</th>
                              <th></th>
                            </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                            <tr>
                              <input type="hidden" name="item_id" value="{{ $row->item_id}}">
                              <td>{{ $row->item_id}}</td>
                              <td>{{ $row->cat_name}}</td>
                              <td><input class="form-control" name="item_name" value="{{$row->item_name}}" /></td>
                              <td><input class="form-control" name="item_price" value="{{$row->item_price}}" /></td>
                              <td><input class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-flat" type="submit" value="Edit"></td>
                            </tr>
                            </tbody>                     
                    </table>
                    </div>
                </form>
            @endif  
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not passing the variable to the view that way; you're actually passing it to the `session()` if you use `->with()`.

This is what you need (pass the params as an array, and it has to be the 2nd parameter of the `view()`:

```
return view('employee', ['emp' => $emp]);
```

Comment: it is not working too... actually m returning the array to the view from where m calling the function